# Google App Script: access denied when trying to create a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I check my Gmail account. If there are new messages with image attachments, I create a subfolder into my Google Drive account, with folder name as email subject, and create a file for every single attachment.

Every thing works well when trying to create subfolder in the root, using `DriveApp.createFolder()`, but I got an error when using `.createFolder()` method of a `Folder` object.

> This is the [link to App script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfoldername) that prove that we can create a folder using a Folder object.

This is the code:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Received photos");
if (!(folders.hasNext())) {
  Logger.log ("Recevied photos folder not found!");  
} else {
  var main_folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log ("Going into " + main_folder.getName());
  var main_folder_id = main_folder.getId();
  
  
  // Move every attachment to right folder
  var folders = main_folder.getFoldersByName(title);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log ("Folder exists" + title);  
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    Logger.log ("Folder " + title + " not exists, I create it");  
    /**********************************************************
    *       THE FOLLOWING ROW GIVE ME ACCESS DENIED ERROR
    ***********************************************************/
    folder = main_folder.createFolder(title);
  }
  
  try {
    attachments.forEach(function (attachment, idx_att)  {
      var moved_file = folder.createFile(attachment);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

I got this error

> Access denied: DriveApp. (riga 57, file "Production")

at this row

```
folder = main_folder.createFolder(title);
```

I checked my logs so I'm sure that `main_folder` is an existing folder.

It's a my folder, it's not shared from someone to me. So, why App script can't create a subfolder into it?

EDIT:

I tried to debug my permission adding these lines

```
Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
var access = main_folder.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser());
Logger.log(access);
```

The users email is right, it's the owner. But the second log line tell me `VIEW`. Now the question is **why can't I have write access yo my folders using this App Script standalone script?**

EDIT 2:

I tried to verify ownership

```
var owner = main_folder.getOwner();
Logger.log(owner.getEmail());
```

What a suprise! The owner email isn't my email but it's the email of the user who shard with me this script... but I verified on Drive and the REAL owner of the main folder is me...

**So what am I doing wrong and how to be able to use a shared script to write into a private folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that my script is owned by a user and it's shared with editing privileges to me.

So `getFoldersByName()` give me not only ONE folder, but a group, because other users have a folder with this name.

So I looped to find the one with right owner

```
              // Because the folder 'Received photos' is present in 
              // a lot of occurencies. The one I need is that with owner = current user
              while (folders.hasNext()) {
                 main_folder = folders.next();
                 if (main_folder.getOwner().getEmail() == Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
                    break; 
                 };
              }

              Logger.log ("Dive into " + main_folder.getName());
              var main_folder_id = main_folder.getId();
```

... and the script now can write into the folder

Of course, for me it's a bug that `getFoldersByName` retrieves folder of script owner instead of current user.

Comment: see similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920379/student-gradebook-unable-to-complete-script-because-of-access-denied-driveapp   "Access denied: DriveApp" when trying to remove a file owned by another user.